# How to Schedule a job run at multiple time intervals

Tags: java, spring, scheduling

We've a simple requirement to download files from different end point servers. We'll be scheduling these file downloads to happen at various time in the day (customizable from the GUI). We've been using Spring Scheduling & its working for a single job to download from a single server.

Now we would like to extend this operation of downloading the files to more than one server & different time. The operation of file downloading is same, but the time at which it will be running, the end point server, the location to download everything will change per task. Basically we'll be parameterizing these attributes & want to reuse the same job to download the files. Is that possible ?

How to achieve this using Spring Scheduling ?

Comment: How about using a simple timer tasks and creating multiple  objects of same and separating the work(downloading files) from timing logic..

Comment: The task that needs to be repeated is the file download. I didn't get what you're trying to mean by Separate the work ? Can you please be bit more elaborate ?

Comment: Ok I will answer this question but can you just specify more on _multiple time intervals_ I dint get this much..

Comment: Regd. the time intervals. Lets say I've 2 servers abc.com & efg.com and I've some 100 files to download from within a directory from each of these servers which I'll pass as parameters. I want to schedule download from abc.com at 5 A.M. and download from efg.com at 5.30 A.M. each task should download the files at the stipulated time configured & no task should wait for the other one to be completed.

Comment: I added the answer. Hope that works.. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The schedule(TimerTask task,long delay,long period) method is used to schedule the specified task for repeated fixed-delay execution, beginning after the specified delay.

```
public class TimerClassExample {
   public static void scheduleTaskOfDownload(Date SchedulerStartTime,Long SchedulerInterval) {
   // creating timer task, timer
   TimerTask tasknew = new MyFileDownloader (serverName);
   Timer timer = new Timer();

   // scheduling the task at interval
   timer.schedule(tasknew,SchedulerStartTime, SchedulerInterval);      
   }

}
```

You can have a timerTask like below from which you can call download logic:-

```
public class MyFileDownloader extends TimerTask {
String serverName;
MyFileDownloader(String serverName){this.serverName= serverName}
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Timer task started at:"+new Date());
        downloadFiles(serverName);//your code which downloads file from server
        System.out.println("Timer task finished at:"+new Date());
    }
}
```

Now when your application starts you can use this code to make a call to our scheduler method scheduleTaskOfDownload

```
@Component
public class StartupHousekeeper implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

  @Override
  public void onApplicationEvent(final ContextRefreshedEvent event) {

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 5);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
           //I am passing same time in both calls but you can pass different dates 
    TimerClassExample.scheduleTaskOfDownload(cal.getTime(),TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(3, TimeUnit.HOURS));
        TimerClassExample.scheduleTaskOfDownload(cal.getTime(),TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(2, TimeUnit.HOURS)); 

   //also keeping interval as 2 and 3 hours respectively but you choose different interval like 24 hrs in that place
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Viraj. The scheduling part I may need it upon a user action not at server startup. That part I'll take care. Accepted your solution as answer.

Comment: @VirajNalawade Is timerTask safe for server crash or sudden server failure? I have a similar use Case but i want reliable way too to achieve this

Comment: @KanikaMann what do you mean by _sudden server failure_ ? If you mean due to some reason servers stops than it is safe and it should not affect TimerTask. I have used it in my clustered app and have many times restarted the server but TimerTask has never created a problem because of sever failure..

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest integrate spring with Quartz job scheduler. Where you can either decide to:
-  use single cron job that runs once in every scheduled time. Each invocation picks up parameters provided from another spring bean or database table.
OR 
- create separate job that triggeres at scheduled time with given parameters.

Comment: Won't creating a separate job for each download task will be an overkill ? And regarding using single cron job for download task at a scheduled time, will it be possible to begin another download if say for example I've scheduled one download at 5 A.M. and another at 5.15 A.M. assuming each download activity takes 30 minutes to complete. Will the second download activity be triggered before the first one is completed ?

Comment: Good answer @charybr.. Yes quartz can be overkill but if you think application might need more scheduling in future.. Quartz is the best option...